# How to provide passed injection from vue functional component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-render-function

Tree:

```html
<Parent>
  <FnChild>
    <Target />
  </FnChild>
</Parent>
```

I have $validator provided by `Parent`.
Inside `FnChild` I use render function with other async component (`Target`).

```js
  inject: ['$validator'],
  render: (h, context) => {
    return h(Target, context.data, context.children)
  }
```

injections live inside `context.injections`, but how to pass it down to the `Target` by using functional component?

I can imagine only rewriting of FnChild as non-functional component and using `provide: ['$validator']` in `FnChild`

**UPD**: as was pointed in answers, you don't need any inject/provide inside functional component, it just works.

My specific case was related to v-validate and auto-injection of new `$validator` in each component. And in my specific case it was a component with slot, which was overriding `$validator` because I had no `inject: ['$validator']` inside it. Structure is a simple like this:

Parent

```
<ComponentWithSlot>
  <FnChild slot='my-slot' />
</ComponentWithSlot>
```

Parent had validator injected, but ComponentWithSlot hadn't, so new instance was recreated by v-validate for ComponentWithSlot and it was provided down to the FnChild instead of `$validator` from `Parent` component.

So once I've added `inject: ['$validator']` into `ComponentWithSlot`, everything is fine and `Target` now correctly receives `$validator` from `Parent`.

Comment: Why do you need to use a render-function in this scenario? I generally avoid using them unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @MJ_Wales I think it's a good idea to use functional components when you don't really need instance or it is a component without any logic (in my case it's just resolver of another async component). So why not to do it more lightweight then? But in vue, it's usually painful to use functional component... because of weird way of working, bugs or weird api.

Comment: Fair enough. I think the issue is a scoping issue. I'll post my thoughts

Comment: I'm unsure sorry, deleted my incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[provide/inject API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) is specifically designed to:

> allow an ancestor component to serve as a dependency injector for all its descendants, regardless of how deep the component hierarchy is, as long as they are in the same parent chain.

1. `FnChild` does't need to use `inject: ['$validator']` at all
2. No need to pass anything related to injections in `FnChild` render function
3. Just use `inject: ['$validator']` in your `Target` async component

Check this [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-796u0)

> provide and inject are primarily provided for advanced plugin / component library use cases. **It is NOT recommended to use them in generic application code.**

Comment: Hm, that's weird, probably I did something wrong somewhere else. Because your example looks correct, thanks.